# How to Cache JSON Objects Into Single File for Faster Page Load Times

Tags: php, json, api, caching, youtube

I have been looking around for a solution to cache multiple JSON Objects into a single file on my server (without a database). The reason for this is because I am developing a site which has multiple JSON requests from users YouTube channels and the page takes a while to load because of this.

A short section of my PHP File which makes the JSON Requests from YouTube (there are a lot more JSON requests in this json-yt.php file:

```
// VNM Jar
$realUserName = 'TheEnijar';
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$TheEnijar = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];

// VNM Jinxed
$realUserName = 'OhhJinxed';
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$OhhJinxed = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];

// VNM Pin
$realUserName = 'ImGreenii';
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$ImGreenii = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];

// VNM Zq
$realUserName = 'Zqonalized';
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$Zqonalized = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];
```

Is this even possible, and if so, can anybody point me in the right direction or provide me with a solution to storing JSON requests prior to the user loading the page and JSON making the request to all the different YouTube channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, there is a LOT of different ways to do this. The simplest is to make an assoc array of your data, serialize it and write to the file.

```
$dataArray = array();

// ...
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');
$dataArray['jinxed'] = $data;

$data = serialize($data);
file_put_contents('cache.txt', $data);
```

Than pull it back:

```
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('cache.txt'));
```

But, as I said, there is a lot of another ways to cache requests. And chosing one of them depends on what else you need from your caching system.

**UPD:** Don't forget that cached info will become outdated sometime, so you must to update your cache every certain period. To not saving any additional values (like cached time) use `filemtime()` function for your cache file.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I was looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
<?php

function getCachableContent($url){
    $hash = md5($url);
    $cacheFile = "/tmp/foo-cache/$hash";
    if ( file_exists($cacheFile) and filemtime($cacheFile) < time() - 300 ) {
        $data = file_get_contents($cacheFile);
    } else {
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($cacheFile, $data);
    }
    return json_decode($data);
}

$data = getCachableContent('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');
```

but I think it's better to use solutions like redis that provides expire time. also you can create a ramdisk for temp directory (if you're using linux) which makes it faster.